# CodedUI Ordered Test stopping after an hour

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to run a set of test that takes longer than an hour to complete.
However once I reach the time span of an hour the test will stop and skip all the test that have not being run.
Any suggestions would be great :)

Comment: Your question is not quite clear - it's actually missing. Do you want to stress test an application for an hour and then terminate the test? Are you able to control the test ending trough code? The `Timer` class could be of use.

Comment: Are there any error messages thrown in your test output? Could there be any rogue configurations? Are you walking away from an unlocked machine, leaving it open for the casual passerby to stop your tests as they see fit?

Comment: I am creating a .orderedtest in vs2012, I run my ordered test and after an hour the test will stop for no reason. There are no error messages, it informs me of what test have passed and which test have failed

Comment: @ConorShannon Try running all of the failed tests in your ordered test on their own. Perhaps those tests are simply failing? Since this is a CodedUI test, it's possible the interaction of the tests preceding the failed tests are causing those tests to fail. Maybe even try putting together an ordered test that contains the last 2 passed test, and then all of the failed tests.

Answer (score 2):

In your Test Settings file, one of the test settings is 'Abort a test run if its total execution time exceeds:' and another is 'Mark an individual test as failed if its execution time exceeds:' - Make sure both of these settings have been adjusted to handle the durations you're after.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the test timeout attribute as shown in this thread: [MSTest: how to increase test time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109781/mstest-how-to-increase-test-time)

```
[TestMethod]
[Timeout(10*60*1000)]
public void Login_ExpirationFail_Test()
{......}
```